# request timeout from flatMapping over cats.effect.IO

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I am attempting to transform some data that is encapsulated in cats.effect.IO with a Map that also is in an IO monad. I'm using http4s with blaze server and when I use the following code the request times out:

```
  def getScoresByUserId(userId: Int): IO[Response[IO]] = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + ShiftJsonSerializer() + RawShiftSerializer()
    implicit val shiftJsonReader = new Reader[ShiftJson] {
      def read(value: JValue): ShiftJson = value.extract[ShiftJson]
    }
    implicit val shiftJsonDec = jsonOf[IO, ShiftJson]

    // get the shifts
    var getDbShifts: IO[List[Shift]] = shiftModel.findByUserId(userId)

    // use the userRoleId to get the RoleId then get the tasks for this role
    val taskMap : IO[Map[String, Double]] = taskModel.findByUserId(userId).flatMap {
      case tskLst: List[Task] => IO(tskLst.map((task: Task) => (task.name -> task.standard)).toMap)
    }

    val traversed: IO[List[Shift]] = for {
      shifts <- getDbShifts
      traversed <- shifts.traverse((shift: Shift) => {
        val lstShiftJson: IO[List[ShiftJson]] = read[List[ShiftJson]](shift.roleTasks)
          .map((sj: ShiftJson) =>
            taskMap.flatMap((tm: Map[String, Double]) =>
              IO(ShiftJson(sj.name, sj.taskType, sj.label, sj.value.toString.toDouble / tm.get(sj.name).get)))
          ).sequence

        //TODO: this flatMap is bricking my request
        lstShiftJson.flatMap((sjLst: List[ShiftJson]) => {
          IO(Shift(shift.id, shift.shiftDate, shift.shiftStart, shift.shiftEnd,
            shift.lunchDuration, shift.shiftDuration, shift.breakOffProd, shift.systemDownOffProd,
            shift.meetingOffProd, shift.trainingOffProd, shift.projectOffProd, shift.miscOffProd,
            write[List[ShiftJson]](sjLst), shift.userRoleId, shift.isApproved, shift.score, shift.comments
          ))
        })
      })

    } yield traversed

  traversed.flatMap((sLst: List[Shift]) => Ok(write[List[Shift]](sLst)))
}
```

as you can see the TODO comment. I've narrowed down this method to the flatmap below the TODO comment. If I remove that flatMap and merely return "IO(shift)" to the traversed variable the request does not timeout; However, that doesn't help me much because I need to make use of the lstShiftJson variable which has my transformed json.

My intuition tells me I'm abusing the IO monad somehow, but I'm not quite sure how.

Thank you for your time in reading this!

Comment: Two things, first you are wrapping in `IO` unnecessary things, for example constructing a **Map** from a * List** is a pure computation, that should have been a `map` instead of a `flatMap` - Second, remember an `IO` is a description of a computation, so every time you `flatMap` over `taskMap` you are executing that whole operation again, including the DB query.

Comment: Thank you for the information Luis! I've posted the answer I came up with below. I don't think it is perfect. particularly the final line that produces the return value. So any comments you have would be much appreciated! thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

So with the guidance of Luis's comment I refactored my code to the following. I don't think it is optimal (i.e. the flatMap at the end seems unecessary, but I couldnt' figure out how to remove it. BUT it's the best I've got.

```
  def getScoresByUserId(userId: Int): IO[Response[IO]] = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + ShiftJsonSerializer() + RawShiftSerializer()
    implicit val shiftJsonReader = new Reader[ShiftJson] {
      def read(value: JValue): ShiftJson = value.extract[ShiftJson]
    }
    implicit val shiftJsonDec = jsonOf[IO, ShiftJson]

    // FOR EACH SHIFT
    // - read the shift.roleTasks into a ShiftJson object
    // - divide each task value by the task.standard where task.name = shiftJson.name
    // - write the list of shiftJson back to a string
    val traversed = for {
      taskMap <- taskModel.findByUserId(userId).map((tList: List[Task]) => tList.map((task: Task) => (task.name -> task.standard)).toMap)
      shifts <- shiftModel.findByUserId(userId)
      traversed <- shifts.traverse((shift: Shift) => {
        val lstShiftJson: List[ShiftJson] = read[List[ShiftJson]](shift.roleTasks)
          .map((sj: ShiftJson) => ShiftJson(sj.name, sj.taskType, sj.label, sj.value.toString.toDouble / taskMap.get(sj.name).get ))
        shift.roleTasks = write[List[ShiftJson]](lstShiftJson)
        IO(shift)
      })
    } yield traversed

    traversed.flatMap((t: List[Shift]) => Ok(write[List[Shift]](t)))
  }
```

1. Luis mentioned that mapping my List[Shift] to a Map[String, Double] is a pure operation so we want to use a map instead of flatMap.
2. He mentioned that I'm wrapping every operation that comes from the database in IO which is causing a great deal of recomputation. (including DB transactions)
3. To solve this issue I moved all of the database operations inside of my for loop, using the "<-" operator to flatMap each of the return values allows the variables being used to preside within the IO monads, hence preventing the recomputation experienced before.

I do think there must be a better way of returning my return value. flatMapping the "traversed" variable to get back inside of the IO monad seems to be unnecessary recomputation, so please anyone correct me.

Comment: It seem `shift` is mutable, I would avoid that but if you can't then the whole body of `traverse` should be inside `IO` because that is a side effect. But, it you can avoid that mutability then you do not need traverse because you can just `map` the list and use `result = shifts.map(???)` inside the for. - The final `flatMap` is correct and is not inefficient, you made add it to the for but the end result would be the same. - Otherwise, the code looks pretty good to me :) nice job! You may want to ask in the **cats-effect** gitter channel if you want more code reviews.

Comment: as one of my processors said, _"there are no stupid questions, the are stupids who don't ask"_ - at the end nobody is forced to answer you, what you can do is ensure the question is of high quality, detach first, try things first, be concise and clear, format your code, etc.